# Math Operations?

Tags: c, math, decimal

This is my first time programming and I am lost. I'm trying to do this math operation but it keeps erroring out and I'm unsure of where the problem is. Also, I can't figure out how to make all numeric output into two decimal places. Please help. This is what I have put so far.

```
int main(void) {
    int distance, time, speed, meters, mts_per_mile, sec_per_mile, mts, mps;
    csis = fopen("csis.txt", "w");

    distance = 425.5;
    time = 7.5;
    speed = distance / time;
    mts_per_mile = 1600;
    sec_per_mile = 3600;
    mts = distance * mts_per_mile;
    mps = mts / sec_per_mile;


    printf("The car going %d miles in %d hours is going at a speed of %d mph.\n", distance, time, speed);
    fprintf("The car going %d miles in %d hours is going at a speed of %d mph.\n", distance, time, speed);
    printf("The car has traveled %d meters total, at a rate of %d meters per second.", mts, mps);
    fprintf("The car has traveled %d meters total, at a rate of %d meters per second.", mts, mps);
    fclose(csis);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, instead of using `int` for variables use `double` or `float`. That would solve your problem .

Comment: `int` stands for [integer](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer).

Comment: you're calling `fprintf` incorrectly

Comment: No declaration for 'csis', no error messages, just 'keeps erroring out'.  That is unhelpful:(

Comment: Side note: The formula for meters per second should be `mps = mts / (sec_per_mile * time)`.   Also, a better name for `sec_per_mile` would be `sec_per_hour`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use 2 decimal places, you need to use double or float variables. Also you forgot to mention the type of your `csis`  variable (which is `FILE*`).
`fprintf()` takes as first argument the `FILE*` handle which you missed. To use two decimal places in output simply use `%.02f` in `printf()/fprint()`.

See also the reference for [printf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) and [fprintf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

int main(void) {
  double distance, time, speed, mts_per_mile, sec_per_mile, mts, mps;
  FILE* csis = fopen("csis.txt", "w");

  distance = 425.5;
  time = 7.5;
  speed = distance / time;
  mts_per_mile = 1600;
  sec_per_mile = 3600;
  mts = distance * mts_per_mile;
  mps = mts / sec_per_mile;

  printf("The car going %.02f miles in %.02f hours is going at a speed of %.02f mph.\n", distance, time, speed);
  fprintf(csis, "The car going %.02f miles in %.02f hours is going at a speed of %.02f mph.\n", distance, time, speed);
  printf("The car has traveled %.02f meters total, at a rate of %.02f meters per second.", mts, mps);
  fprintf(csis, "The car has traveled %.02f meters total, at a rate of %.02f meters per second.", mts, mps);
  fclose(csis);
  return 0;
}
```

will output:

> The car going 425.50 miles in 7.50 hours is going at a speed of 56.73
>   mph. The car has traveled 680800.00 meters total, at a rate of 189.11
>   meters per second.

Comment: It would be more conventional to use `%.2f`; the zero serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

All of your variables are of type `int`, which only stores integral values.

`425.5` will be converted to an `int` as `425` (rounding occurs toward zero).  Similarly, `7.5` will be converted as `7`.

Diving two `int`s (`425` by `7`) will also produce an integral value, with rounding toward zero therefore produce `60`.

If your compiler has an `int` type that can't support values more than `32767` (the C standard requires actually no more than that), then the calculation `60*1600*3600` will overflow.   The result of that is called undefined behaviour, and one possible symptom is "erroring out".

If you want non-integral real values, make the variables of type `float` or `double`.   And change the format specifiers to output them from `%d` to `%f`.   To output to 2 decimal places, use the format `%.02f`.

Comment: It would be more conventional to use `%.2f`; the zero serves no purpose.